# How do I access the old bottom indicator apps in 17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10

As my particular example, I had some indicators that used to be in GNOME's bottom left, in a really stupid-looking menu. Now, however, I cannot start them. Run them from the start menu, nothing. Run them from command line, still no GUI popping up.

Comment: That menu in the lower-left corner of the screen has been removed in the final release of 17.10. You can try to enable the gnome extension called `Ubuntu AppIndicators` to try to get them back, but they'll appear in the top-right of your top panel now.

Comment: Could you link? No results for "ubuntu appindicators" on https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: `Ubuntu AppIndicators` is built into 17.10. Activate it by using the `Gnome Tweak Tool` or by going to `https://extensions.gnome.org/` and selecting to view installed extensions.

Comment: Ubuntu AppIndicators doesn't work. It doesn't show the icons. TopIcons Plus does.

Comment: Are you running xorg or wayland? Do you have `indicator-application` installed?

Comment: wayland (default) running indicator-application in terminal yielded command not found. I'm in an almost totally stock 17.10  installation.

Comment: To see if you have `indicator-application` installed, in `terminal` do `dpkg -l indicator-application`. You probably don't on a clean stock 17.10 install. If you disable TopIcons, enable `Ubuntu AppIndicators` in the Gnome extensions, and restart the gnome-shell with `alt-f2` then `r` then `enter key`, do the icons appear in the top-right of the upper panel?

Comment: restart is not available on wayland.

Comment: but turning topicons plus on always returns the icons to the top middle-left, even after turning it off, and/or turning on appindicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try TopIcons available on https://extensions.gnome.org .

The Tweak tool also already has the Ubuntu appindicators extension installed by default.

Comment: Ubuntu appindicators extension doesn't show the icons when activated. Topicons Plus does. I'm in 17.10.